# Textbook's reference - Euler Totient's function (proof/derivation by the use of inclusion-exclusion princple)

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, inclusion-exclusion, totient-function

Wonder, in which textbooks is a proof/derivation of formula of Euler's totient function by the use inclusion-exclusion principle from combinatorial analysis.

Putting references below this post very appreciated!

Comment: I will add a combinatorial proof on my post on your previous post.

Comment: Thanks! Looking forward to seeing it :)

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734597/inclusion-exclusion-principle-challenging-problem).

Comment: Saw that. But simply due to curiosity I wonder about which textbooks mention this problem.

Comment: My answer is edited